# Event ID 37: kernel processor power and problems shutting down

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu, power-supply, event-log

HP Pavilion dv6610eg

**Changes**

2 weeks ago I:

- cleaned my notebook and renewed thermal material (thermal paste and thermal pads)
- replaced the HDD with a Samsung 128GB SSD: I can only use it in IDE mode, because the BIOS has no option for switching to SATA AHCI
- removed the DVD drive (I did not replace it)
- renewed the USB/power connector board (HP spare part number is 449454-001 and the replacement has exactly this number)
- renewed the external PSU with a universal notebook PSU, I set the voltage to 18.5 V

I did not re-install Windows 7 after these changes, but just cloned the HDD to the SSD.
Then it worked for 2 weeks without any problems.
The temperature of CPU is usually < 60°, GPU and chipset <= 80° even under heavy load, that is less than before.

**1.1 Initial problems**
1 week ago suddenly the notebook froze with a black screen when shutting down, switching to standy or hibernation. After some minutes a blue screen "driver failure power state" appeared.

**1.2 Solution attempt: Windows reinstallation**
 I re-installed Windows 7 and the driver from the NVIDIA website for NVIDIA GeForce 7150M/ nForce 630.
I also tried the driver provided on the HP Pavilion dv6610eg website. The problem still existed. However, the BSOD did not appear again.

Then I removed the battery from the notebook and inserted it again and shutting down, ... did not freeze anymore.

**2. 1 New problems**

Mostly these messages appeared in the Windows event log:
 -       event ID 37: kernel processor power (the speed of the CPU is limited by the system firmware)
 -       event ID 19: WHEA logger (processor core, exception when checking the computer, unkonwn error)
 -       event ID 18: WHEA logger (processor core, critical hardware failure, unknown error)
            once there was a cache hierarchy error instead of an unknown error
 -   event ID 12: HAL (memory was damaged by the system firmware)

**2.2 Solution attempt: Update BIOS**

I updated the BIOS from version F.32 to F.34 from the HP website.

Now the WHEA logger did not appear again.

**3.1 New/remaining problems**

However, event ID 37 is still there and there is a new event ACPI event id 13.

When I tried to shutdown the notebook after updating the BIOS the screen got black, but it did not turn off. I powered it off hardly and restarted. It started without problems, but the problem shutting down remained. So I removed the battery and now shutting down seems to work.

Event ID 37 still exists and the perceived performance of the system is lower than before. Furthermore I ran a benchmark with 3DMark06, because it is the only bechmark for this CPU, that I could find reference data for. In the internet this CPU reaches about 1300 points, but my notebook's CPU only reached about 800.

I started Prime95.

After some time (~20 minutes) one of the two workers reported this:

Self-test 768K passed!FATAL ERROR: Rounding was 0.5, expected less than 0.4
Hardware failure detected, consult stress.txt file.

**3.2 Successless solution attempts**

- I can not change any power options in the BIOS, because my BIOS in general provides very little options.
- I tried my previous external PSU again, same behavior.
- Running a stress test with HeavyLoad (CPU, SSD, GPU) for almost 2 hours did not cause any problems or event log entries.
- MemTestx86+ reported nothing after running it 2 hours.
- Steps described in this article, except from disassembling my notebook: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/bugcheck-code-124/98c998d2-447a...
- Windows energy saving plan is set to maximum performance.

What can I do?

**Attachments**

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvN-6zW5d3EPgj-uro8BLYxfVngI

- Windows event log filtered for warnings, errors and critical messages.
- filtered event log
- HWinfo log
- HWinfo sensor log
- Minidump caused by the BSOD "driver failure power state" before re-installing Windows 7, there were a lot minidumps looking like this.
- Minidump after re-installing Windows 7, I do not know why this minidump was created at all, because I have not seen a bluescreen and it is the only one.
- msinfo file

Comment: Try aida64 or hot cpu tester, maybe you learn something new. Kernel power is usually caused by energy settings, try with performance settings and turn off everything possible in energy settings on windows and in bios. For example EIST, CxE, etc... Log the temperature with HwInfo, maybe you find that the CPU is overheating. I had similar issues with a 775 mobo and a 771 Xeon, I forgot to mod the BIOS to support the CPU. It worked with the other microcode, but I had these kernel power errors, and video driver restarts, the mobo thought the temperature is 20°C higher, etc... It was hard to debug.